# Passing an inner class which implements an interface

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

Say I have the following:

```
public class A {
  //stuff
  public class B implements I {}
}

public interface I {}

public class Foo {
  int bar(I i) {}
}
```

Now why does Java give me a build error of 'not applicable for type...' when I try to pass an instance of B to Foo.bar() inside the body of class A?

Is the inner class not considered a proper implementation of I because it is contained inside a top-level class?

Cheers, Dave.

Comment: If included the call to Foo.bar and the compiler error message, people will be able to help better.

Comment: Right now I'm simply calling I i = new B(); 

I'm guessing it forces you to say I i = A.B() or similar...?

Comment: `new Foo().bar(new A().new B());`

Comment: call : `I i = new A().new B();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a Instance of class A, before you can create a instance of object B (because B is a inner class of A).
Try this code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
A a = new A();
B b = a.new B();
foo.bar(b);
```

Comment: That works, but is just horrible. Inner classe instances should really only be created from their containing instance (like @aioobe did in his example).

Comment: yep, cheers. 


I'd confused myself because the code I'm editing isn't quite as simple as the example above - the A.B type is inside a list, etc. The design of the class isn't fit for its purpose anyway, so time for some refactoring. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, you are right - it is horrible. But it explains the problem, i think.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you may have two different `I` interfaces. Make sure you import the same ones in both files.

This is the exact error you get (from Eclipse) if you accidentally use two different interfaces with the same name.

> ```
> The method bar(I) in the type Foo is not applicable for the arguments (A.B)
> ```

---

For reference, this compiles fine for me:

```
class A {
    // stuff
    public void test() {
        new Foo().bar(new B());
    }

    public class B implements I {
    }
}

interface I {
}

class Foo {
    int bar(I i) {
        return 0;    // note that you need a return value for it to compile.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, ignore the obvious ;) That's not the issue... talking more about the inner class instantiation.

Comment: One note, if you are going to use B only in the bar() method, then probaly the better approach is to use anonymous inner class:
new Foo().bar(new I(){});

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `B` has an inplicit reference to `A`, so you need an `A` (the `this` inside a method of `A`, of a `new A()` outside the context of `A`) If in your application `B` is an `I` in the namespace of `A` without actually using the implicit reference between `B` and `A`, you should declare the inner class `static`:

```
public class A {
  //stuff
  public static class B implements I {}
}

public interface I {}

public class Foo {
  int bar(I i) {}
}
```

Now the following should work:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
B b = new A.B();
foo.bar(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's fine , but if the inner class which implement an interface is defined within grails service.

In that case how we will instantiate ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)